# WP Elegant Themes > hide tinymce buttons?

Tags: wordpress, themes

I have an elegant theme installed in my Wordpress website, and I am wondering how i can hide or remove the shortcode buttons in the tinymce (thing) that are generated by the Elegant Theme (admin area WP). I have been trying to look up the action hook and remove it and also play with the CSS of the buttons, but nothing helped. any idea's on how to remove these small buttons from the backend of my WP website?

This is the related code I've found:

```
add_filter('mce_buttons', 'et_filter_mce_button'); 

add_filter('mce_external_plugins', 'et_filter_mce_plugin'); 

function et_filter_mce_button($buttons) { 
    array_push( $buttons, '|', 'et_learn_more', 'et_box', 'et_button', 'et_tabs', 'et_author' ); 
    return $buttons; 
}
```

Comment: Search for `"tiny_mce_"` in the theme files, analyze and post the results.

Comment: hi,thanks for your reply. I did a lot of searching. I know how to get rid of it but i really would like to just add something in the functions.php instead of making direct changes in the template files. Code found is like `add_filter('mce_buttons', 'et_filter_mce_button'); add_filter('mce_external_plugins', 'et_filter_mce_plugin');` and `function et_filter_mce_button($buttons) { array_push( $buttons, '|', 'et_learn_more', 'et_box', 'et_button', 'et_tabs', 'et_author' ); return $buttons; }`

maybe disabling these functions in functions.php could work? Any ideas?

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/mce_buttons,_mce_buttons_2,_mce_buttons_3,_mce_buttons_4

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/mce_external_plugins

Answer (score 0):

Create a [plugin](http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin) and [remove the filters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_filter):

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Remove ET MCE Buttons
 */

add_action( 'admin_init', 'remove_et_so_19084867' );

function remove_et_so_19084867() {
    remove_filter( 'mce_buttons', 'et_filter_mce_button' );
    remove_filter( 'mce_external_plugins', 'et_filter_mce_plugin' );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A user from the Elegant Themes forum referenced this post: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/103347/removing-buttons-from-the-editor and said:

Place the following code in your child theme functions.php:

```
// HIDE TINYMCE CUSTOM BUTTONS

function tinymce_editor_buttons($buttons) {
return array();
}

function tinymce_editor_buttons_second_row($buttons) {
return array();
}

add_filter("mce_buttons", "tinymce_editor_buttons", 99);
add_filter("mce_buttons_2", "tinymce_editor_buttons_second_row", 99);
```

This removes all buttons inserted by Divi and other plugins. If you need to keep any buttons you can include the corresponding ID inside of `return array();`. Also, if you're using the plugin [TinyMCE Advanced](https://wordpress.org/plugins/tinymce-advanced/), the standard buttons stay in place anyway.